# How to download a specific CA (certificate authority) which a website is using and add it to linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, ssl, certificate

I need to connect to a URL from Linux terminal but seemingly Ubuntu doesn't have the https certificate to connect to them. I open the website in my browser whit no problem. Is clicking on the lock icon in the address bar of the browser and downloading the two *.pem* files from there the right way to download the certificates? If i do that I'm stuck with two files called cert and chain which I don't know add to the Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Not enough info and what there is is garbled. If chrome can connect without a warning, then you have the root certs already in place, so why should it fail from the cli?

Comment: Well what I learned from some question and answer in this site is that browsers (in my case firefox actually) have their own certificates which is different from the root certificates. Also I provided as much info as I knew myself, please ask if you need to know something specific